# Как устранить ошибку установки сервера при открытии контейнера в vscode?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, containers

Необходимо открыть контейнер в vscode с помощью расширения `dev containers`. Расширение установил, контейнер запустил, нажимаю `attach to vscode`, открывается новое окно и начинается подготовка к открытию контейнера в vscode, но на установке `vscode server` в удаленной среде неминуемо получаю ошибку:

```
[7026 ms] Installing VS Code Server for commit 5e805b79fcb6ba4c2d23712967df89a089da575b
[7029 ms] Start: Downloading VS Code Server
[7029 ms] 5e805b79fcb6ba4c2d23712967df89a089da575b linux-x64 stable 
[27097 ms] read ECONNRESET
[27098 ms] Retrying to download VS Code Server.
[77275 ms] Error: XHR timeout: undefinedms
    at v.ontimeout (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:72:1634)
```

Это часть лога, но в остальной его части *все идёт по плану* (вот здесь ворвался Егор Летов).

Нашел тред на гитхабе с похожей проблемой, но так и не понял как это решить.
Ссылка на тред: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/7073